# Meaning of Phrasal verb "hook up"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please tell me what “hooking up” means in the following dialogue (from Hemingway’s newly discovered short story ["Pursuit as Happiness"](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2020/06/08/pursuit-as-happiness))?

“Hook her up, Josie!” I yelled. “He’s taking all of it.” [i.e., the marlin is pulling all the line out.]

“She’s hooked up, Cap. There he goes.”

As you surely see, ‘her’ and ‘she’ refer to their fishing boat and ‘he’ is the big marlin that has been hooked and is pulling the line out.

Meaning of hooking up is clear in sentences like “. . . forgot to hook the boat up to the trailer!” and “Did you ever hook the boat up to the tow vehicle?” but I can’t get the meaning of it in the above-mentioned dialogue.

Comment: It being a "newly discovered" text, we don't have access to the full context unless you provide it here. But from what I know about Hemingway  (and marlins), it could be he's asking Josie to fasten various belts and straps around some special "big game fisherman" seat bolted into the structure of the boat, so he can strap ***himself*** in there with the rod and line, and spend the next several minutes (or *hours*?) engaged in a trial of strength and endurance  with the hapless marlin. I doubt "her" refers to the fish though. Hemingway being a "man's man" wouldn't fight a "lady" fish.

Comment: ...or perhaps they're in a larger vessel, and the idea is for the fisherman to have that trial of strength after getting into a much smaller boat that the marlin might even be able to tow around for hours until he's exhausted. I don't know what passed for "sport" among such people.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I added a link to the text.  Your guesses seem totally reasonable, but it looks like the narrator wasn't yet in the in the chair.  The next sentence after the quoted text is, "By now I had one foot braced against the stem of the Anita and the other leg against the starboard anchor."  Anyway, the meaning is still not clear to me.  I also assumed "she" and "her" would be some part of the tackle, but there's no mention of changing the tackle at that point.  It's possible that "hook her up" meant *speed up the boat*: "...in spite of the Anita going full speed after the fish."

Comment: *It's possible that "hook her up" meant speed up the boat* No - it would never mean that.  "Her" probably refers to the harness. Probably he was already wearing it but not attached.

Comment: Could be @chaslyfromUK.  It's later mentioned that he's wearing a harness.  On the other hand, he's still moving around the ship at that point: "Then I remember watching her while I reeled and then working my way back to the stern and watching the ship pick up her speed."

Comment: If you ever watch 'Jaws', there is a scene where the shark takes the bait and begins to run off.  The rod and line is hooked-up to the structure of the boat to prevent it flying out of Quint's hands due to the power of the fish pulling on the line.

Comment: Note that "hook up" has easily a dozen different connotations.

Answer (score 2):

It means *full speed*:

> “[Go full speed], Josie!” I yelled. “He’s taking all of it.”
>
> “She’s [at full speed], Cap. There he goes.”
>
> . . . The reel was too hot to hold and the core of line on it was getting
> thinner and thinner in spite of the Anita going **full speed** after the
> fish.
>
> “Can you get any more [speed] out of her?” I called to Mr. Josie.
>
> “Not in this world,” he said. “What you got left?”
>
> “Damn little.”

It appears to be era-specific (Hemingway's story is set in 1933) engine lingo. Search *"hook her up" boat speed* and *"hook up the engine"*.

Here is some [1931 testimony from a New York Supreme Court Case on Appeal](https://books.google.com/books?id=izpgS1yVoE4C&pg=RA11-PA75&lpg=RA11-PA75&dq=%22Hook+her+up%22+boat+speed+up&source=bl&ots=R4kzFocVr2&sig=ACfU3U2oYhzRs5bFqp4VmJKOzocczArVdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3hsG3x5jqAhVBvZ4KHTdUBOwQ6AEwBHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Hook%20her%20up%22%20boat%20speed%20up&f=false):

> **Q.** Hook her up does not mean to put up a line on the boat? **A.** No, sir.
>
> **Q.** Or to fasten her up to the boat, but it means to hook the engine's valve up, so that she has full steam, and that means, in
> other words, full speed? **A.** It gives that word to the captain, to
> the pilot house, and he maneuvers it with bells to hook the boat up to
> work it on the ship.
>
> **Q.** (By the Court:) So that it will go fast, is that it? **A.** Fast, yes, sir.
>
> **Q.** So that when pilot Shooks on the bridge of the steamer said to the tugboat to hook her up, he was giving her an order to go full
> speed ahead? **A.** Yes, sir.

Here's [an excerpt from Zane Grey's *An American Angler in Australia*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0608241.txt) (1937):

> "There's a fin!" yelled Bill, suddenly. He was up on deck. "Far ahead
> and going fast."
>
> "Chase it," I ordered. "Hook her up, Pete."
>
> We ran down current like the wind . . . Peter saw him again and that
> encouraged us. He opened up the engine full ahead and we roared over
> the swells, leaving a white wake behind us.
>
> "There he is!" shouted Peter, pointing. "Going like one thing!"
>
> "Don't run him down, Peter," I said, as I caught my first glimpse of
> the big gleaming tail fin. "It's a black Marlin."
>
> Peter slowed down. But we had to go at least at a ten-knot speed in
> order to come up with the fish. His tail went under, came up again,
> flashed opal and gold, vanished, to show once more.

.

Further reading: [Hooking up the engine](http://www.stanleymotorcarriage.com/SteamEngine/EngineHookUpVideo.htm)

Comment: You don't include the excerpt that might look convincing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Here's the missing line, "...Or to fasten her up to the boat, but it means to hook the engine's valve up, so that she has full steam, and that means, in other words, full speed? A. It gives that word to the captain, to the pilot house, and he maneuvers it with bells to hook the boat up to work it on the ship. Q. (By the Court:) So that it will go fast, is that it? A. Fast, yes, sir.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I still don't know what you mean; I linked precisely to that passage.

Comment: When I clicked, I could only see a little bit of it. I presume that is what @Edwin Ashworth meant. Anyway, I'm upvoting your answer because it looks very convincing. I've simply given a larger chunk of the text in my comment.

Comment: P.S. It is always preferred to quote the passage in your answer as well as just giving a link. Links have a habit of changing and thus leading nowhere.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Thanks; I will update my answer to reflect some search result passages.

Comment: *Going like one thing!* looks odd to me. I assume it's equivalent to my *Going like **anything**!* = *Going **at full speed***. Certainly not common though - most of the handful of Google hits I got for it were exactly the cited usage here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [**III.** Phrases, special collocations, and combinations. **14. k.** *like one thing*, ‘like anything’. *Austral. colloq.* and *U.S. dial.*](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00251145)

Comment: The version of OED I can access has Phrase Defn 3h: colloquial (originally Australian). *like one thing: = **like anything** at anything pron., n., and adv.* I must say I find it odd that your one includes ***and U.S. dial.***, which mine doesn't. Apparently mine is more recent, 'cos the last definition (#17) is: colloquial (originally U.S.). ***A genuine phenomenon, established practice, or discernible trend*** - which meaning wasn't recorded until 2000.  How could "dialectal pockets" of "Australianisms" arise in the US? (I suspect they just guessed that one, then thought better of it! :)